# Calculate second point of line by length and slope

Tags: c#, wpf, math

I'm kinda stuck by this problem, where i try to change the length of a drawn line by moving the second point and keeping its slope.

Note: all this is drawn on a canvas in wpf.

I calculated the slope:

```
var slope = (point2Y - point1Y) / (point2X - point1X);
```

By using the arc tan function, i was able to calculate my `alpha` slope-angle.

```
var alpha = Math.Atan(slope);
```

Now i'm using `Math.Cos` and `Math.Sin` to get the cooridinates of my new point.

```
var xNew = point1X + length * Math.Cos(alpha);
var yNew = point1Y + length * Math.Sin(alpha);
```

This turns out good in two of 4 cases.
But in the other two cases, the points seem to get "placed on the wrong side".

I'm no mathematician and cant find a proper solution after serveral trials.

I appreaciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Atan2`:

```
var alpha = Math.Atan2(point2Y - point1Y, point2X - point1X);
```

---

Or don't use any trigonometry at all:

```
var p1 = new Point(point1X, point1Y);
var p2 = new Point(point2X, point2Y);

var diff = p2 - p1; // a Vector
diff.Normalize();

var p3 = p1 + length * diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that does not require trigonometry.

```
Dx= P2x - P1x
Dy= P2y - P1y
R= L / √(Dx² + Dy²)

P3x = P1x + R . Dx
P3y = P1y + R . Dy
```